# Trying to update ADT - receiving "conflicting dependency" error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've had a series of problems ever since I tried to import an android project.

1. The location of my `SDK` hasn't been set up in preferences (even though it had been before and ADT was working perfectly fine).
2. When I try to set the path to the sdk folder, it says

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.  Please update ADT to the latest version.
>
> So I try to update Eclipse by the following as suggested on another SO post (since "Check for updates" keeps telling me that there are no updates available:
>
> > Help -> Install new software -> p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ -> Check developer tools -> Next
> >     
> >     And that's where I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
ADT CDT Integration 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk 23.0.2.1259578)
ADT CDT Integration 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: ADT Package 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 22.6.2

Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]

Cannot satisfy dependency: 
From: Android Native Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk [23.0.2.1259578]

Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Native Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508  (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
```

How can I successfully get around these errors and update eclipse?

Comment: Personally, I uninstalled the previous ADT tools and installed the newest version. Otherwise I couldn´t get it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TODAY, I got the same error as you:

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

YOUR MESSAGE:

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508. Please update ADT to the latest version.

I fixed it in 5 minutes:

1-Make sure you still have the zip file (me it's "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321")

2-Copy the contents of the zip where you want it to be

3-It's like 1.30 GB (I think), so depending on your computer it could take a few minutes

4-Once it's copied, open it.

5-Go in the eclipse folder, then open the eclipse application (you can even pin it to the taskbar if you use it a lot)

I had this problem a few times, and this always works for me.

Comment: I would accept this but I can't test it right now so I don't know for sure if it'll work. If this works for anyone, comment here so I can accept this answer.

Comment: Well, it worked for me. I'm dead serious, this is what I did.

Comment: Hi, Please could you explain where you find the zip file, and where you should copy its contents to?

Comment: Somehow I can add comments with my cellphone... I created another answer below, so make sure to check it out. Also... If somehow you are not able to delete your old folder with the extracted files, you can go in the task manager and end the process "adb.exe".

Answer (score 4):

Just uninstall current  ADT version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 by going to *Help>Installation Details> installed software* and then select ADT(old version)> click uninstall. Now reinstall latest ADT. This way, I was able to update ADT to current version, hope it helps. 
Note: This won't work on adt-bundle.

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to work. But when it told me to restart ADT at the end, when I restarted, the application would not open.

Comment: which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: if still problem exists try deleting **com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_23.0.0.1245622** folder inside your **eclipse>plugin** directory and resinstall plugin again.

Comment: Trying your option @Trust didnt work, actually now eclipse cant even load

Comment: My solution was to simply delete adt, and redownload the newest version manually from the website.

Comment: after uninstalling, Eclipse said it needed to restart for changes to take effect, now OSX "The application Eclipse can't be opened. -10810"

Comment: ^ I had the same error. Just delete your eclipse folder and redownload from developer.android.com.

Comment: @JohnB I already added that it won't work on adt-bundle. Please read answer carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall all the conflicting components.
In my case, Open-GL, DDMS, ADT etc were conflicting with the update.
So i uninstalled all of these,  using..

Help-> About Eclipse SDK->Installation details-> select the  component to uninstall-> uninstall

Then update your ADT.

Help->Install New software-> Select the Adt update site(https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ if not present add it) in available s/w sites. 
And update the ADT.

Comment: I am not able to uninstall ADT also.. what can i do to update to latest version..

Answer (score 0):

For Sanjay Manohar:

Basically, when you downloaded eclipse, it was in a zip file. You needed to extract the files in order to use its content. The file that I downloaded was named "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321" and I got it from "https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html".

If you are using eclipse, you probably have the zip file in your downloads, so no need to download it again.

If I was you, I would make a file named "ANDROID" and in it place the zip file (to use as a future backup if you have similar problems)

I would also create a folder named workspace for all my projects, and a folder named ADT in which I would extract the contents of the zip file.

This would be the folders inside "ANDROID":

-ADT (->contains the extracted files of the zip file "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321")

-workspace (->contains my projects)

-adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321 (->the zip file)

Sorry for creating a new answer, I don't have the reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Just select ADT from Developer tools drop down